# relative accuracy in FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, precision-and-accuracy

In my code I have function which takes large value, e.g. `y[x_]=10^15 (2 - x^2)`
When I try to find a root for such function, `FindRoot` reports it 
does not succeded:

```
x1 = x /. FindRoot[ y[x] == 0, {x, 1, 2}];
x1 // FullForm

FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

1.4142135623730951`
```

in fact, it's correct answer

```
Sqrt[2.] // FullForm

1.4142135623730951`
```

I understand that `FindRoot` checks  the *absolute* error of function value in subsequent steps, $(y_{i+1}-y_i)< \epsilon $. Is there any way to force  `FindRoot` to test *relative* error, that means $\frac{(y_{i+1}-y_i)}{y_i} < \epsilon$ ?

Comment: Is it clear that ${(y_{i+1}-y_i)}/{y_i}$ converges to zero?  In a well-behaved Newton's method problem at a simple root, I think it should converge to `1`.

Comment: you're right, if the root is simple ($y'(x_{root})\neq 0$) the ratio goes to 1. But what happens for double  root,  $y'(x_{root}) = 0$ ?

Comment: If the root is of multiplicity $n$, then the ratio converges to $1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n$.

Answer (score 3):

```
y[x_] = 10^15 (2 - x^2);
```

Specify a `WorkingPrecision` for `FindRoot`. This results in the use of arbitrary-precision rather than machine precision.

```
x1 = (x /. FindRoot[y[x] == 0, {x, 1, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> #]) & /@ {20, 
   25, 30}

(* {1.4142135623730950488, 
    1.414213562373095048801689, 
    1.41421356237309504880168872421} *)

y /@ x1

(* {0.*10^-5, 0.*10^-10, 0.*10^-15} *)
```

Note that there is a significant loss of precision (15 digits).

**EDIT:** In this case `Simplify` resolves the problem since it will remove the constant factor.

```
x1 = x /. FindRoot[y[x] == 0 // Simplify, {x, 1, 2}]

(* 1.41421 *)
```

Comment: you're right, it's a typo, it should be 10^15(2-x^2), I've corrected .